# How to search SQL by value length?

Tags: sql

I tried < and > but it returns with the numbers inside the value,
i want to search the length of value
as example
XXX is a value

How to search it by length = 3

Comment: Is the field varchar or numeric?

Comment: For sql server, use [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
where len(column_name) = 3
```

Answer (score 6):

**MySQL:**

If `value` is a char based type you can simply use `LENGTH(column)=3`
If it is a numerical value you can use `(FLOOR(LOG10(column))+1)=3` (for positive numbers).

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding criteria in the where clause => Where LEN("Column Name") = 3